# Почему *ngIf всегда в else?

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

Подскажите в чем причина, такого поведения *ngIf - всегда срабатывает else и соответственно mat-spinner крутиться постоянно даже когда данные уже в observable. Проверял с http запросом и все работает как надо. В чем ошибка и как исправить данную проблему?Возможно сервис не правильно написан. Заранее всем спасибо.
Код сервиса:

```
    getCerts(): Observable<any> {
    const editorExtensionId = 'sdfsdf';
    const message = {
      cmd: 'sdfsdf',
      args: 'sdfsdf',
    };
    return new Observable<UserKey>(observer => {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, message, res => {
        observer.next(res);
        observer.complete();
       });
     });
    }
```

И код компоненты:

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="certs$ | async as cert; else loading">
    <app-auth [cert]="cert">
    </app-auth>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #loading>
    <mat-spinner>
    </mat-spinner>
  </ng-template>
</app-layout-auth>

      certs$: Observable<UserKey>;
  constructor( private authService: AuthService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): any {
    this.certs$ = this.authService.getCerts();
  }
```

Comment: во1х там не false. во2х функция-producer которую ты объявил внутри `new Observable` в методе `getCerts` имеет несколько return стейтментов, значит какое-то условие выполняется, функция-producer прерывает выполнение и обзервер не генерит событие

Comment: Если дебажить данный участок кода, ни в 1 return не попадаю. А еще если сделать так, this.authService.getCerts().subscribe( p => console.log(p)), то P будет объекту который нужен. Но если присвоить переменную чему либо и через ngIf проверять, то снова ngIf в else будет вечно.

Comment: чему равно `res`? создай _минимальный воспроизводимый пример_, я не сторонник поверхностного гадания и задавания огромного кол-ва вопросов

Comment: res равен объекту, который и должен быть.